# Postgresql : syntax error at and near null

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a web application that is connected to postgresql. I'm trying to get data from the database with a prepared statement and continuously get syntax error at or near null .

Following is my code snippet for query:

```java
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * "+ "FROM rooms1 o " + "JOIN rooms2 op" +
                                                 " ON o.room_id = op.room_id " +"JOIN rooms3 p " +
                                                 " ON op.person_id = p.person_id " +
                                                 "WHERE o.room_id = ? " +
                                                 " ORDER BY o.plate_order ASC;")) {
  //Rest of code
```

this query works fine when check on test database but when use it inside prepared statement it gives error as

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "null"
position: 54
```

From some research I think that problem is with my query, also this is my first time writing Postgresql queries. please have look at it .

Comment: Are you absolutely certain all your parameters are set to sensible values?

Comment: Restating the question here from Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen asked, just to clarify - are you setting a parameter value for the prepared statement before executing it (e.g. ' pstmt.setString(1,"RM123");  ') ?  are you possibly sending a null value?

Comment: yes i'm pretty sure about it .

Comment: You should be able to get actual query sent to server by searching text log. This error indicates that query structure is wrong, not values sent to prepared statement (I believe it is not possible to cause this error once statement was prepared). You should be able to find logs in location set by `SELECT string_agg(setting, '/' ORDER BY name) FROM pg_catalog.pg_settings WHERE name IN('data_directory', 'log_filename', 'log_directory');`

Comment: You are probably not executing the query you think you are.  Look in the PostgreSQL server's log file to find the query with the error, without the obfuscation of the client library getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

o.room_id = ? if ? is null so u have to check "o.room_id is null". u can check this with inline if

Comment: Unlikely to solve this issue, since comparing column to NULL value using `=` operator while does not make sense, will not result in error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have indicated the error position 54 with `***`:

```
SELECT * FROM rooms1 o
JOIN rooms2 op ON o.room_id = ***op.room_id
JOIN rooms3 p  ON op.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE o.room_id = ?
ORDER BY o.plate_order ASC
```

I do not entirely understand the error message but
op.room_id perhaps has null occurrences.

Weird error IMHO, but try a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT o.*, op.*, p.* FROM rooms1 o
LEFT JOIN rooms2 op ON o.room_id = op.room_id
LEFT JOIN rooms3 p  ON op.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE o.room_id = ?
ORDER BY o.plate_order ASC
```

(The semicolon `;` at the end is superfluous.)

Comment: It would not result in error if one the JOIN columns contained NULL values; it would simply not JOIN those rows, so LEFT JOIN will not solve it.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński indeed, I already was wondering whether `SELECT *` was expanded to the actual columns, for position 54 to point to some null. Unfortunately never much experience with Postgresql.